# Computer locks up while compiling specific program; how can I diagnose the issue?

Tags: cpu, freeze

I have an AMD Ryzen ThreadRipper that has been working really well. I've compiled all kinds of stuff with no problem and have stress-tested the CPU with no issues discovered. I'm not overclocking. I'm running Arch Linux.

When I compile Litecoin from source, my computer always locks up on one specific file during compilation. It's always the same file and it always hardlocks my computer. The mouse no longer moves and the caps lock key no longer toggles on my keyboard. The only way to recover is to reset the computer.

I'm assuming this is a hardware problem of some kind since no software should be able to do that, but how can I further diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging, I discovered that my system runs out of RAM (I have 32 GB) while compiling some of the C++ files. When this happens, other processes start dying, ultimately leading to the symptoms I experienced.

I discovered this by attempting the compile from a non-graphical tty.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely some kind of software error; the caps lock light is provided by a keyboard driver (albeit a very fast, low-level one, so you almost never hit that kind of freeze).

I'm not sure you can do anything here; most likely, the Litecoin developers haven't compiled on an AMD Ryzen, so this isn't a supported scenario. If I had to guess, this is because the compiler/toolchain scripts are assuming some Intel-specific behavior that doesn't happen on your system.